# Consulta a base de datos

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estoy trabajando con el código de alguien más, es una mezcla de programación estructurada, POO, MVC.

Dentro de un archivo **tarea_model.php** tengo dos métodos, el primero `getTareasPendientes` aplica filtros y hace la consulta con la base de datos para arrojar el **array** de las tareas pendientes del empleado como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Tareas Pendientes]

El segundo método `cancelTareasP`(en el que me encuentro trabajando), cancelará las tareas pendientes de un proyecto en específico y registrará los cambios en un historial.

Lo que quiero es sacar sólo el `id` de las tareas pendientes en el método `getTareasPendientes` y utilizarlo en el método `cancelTareasP`, ya que para registrar los cambios en el historial debo realizar la consulta y `Update` de cada tarea por separado.

Espero me haya logrado explicar y a pesar de que no puedo poner todo el código logre entenderse.

### tarea_model.php

```
<?php    

    /**
     * Devuelve arreglo de tareas PENDIENTES asociadas al Empleado.
     * @param  SafeMySQL $db    Conex. a BD
     * @param  integer    $idEmp ID del Empleado (opcional)
     * @param  array    $aFiltro Arreglo para aplicar filtros personalizados a la consulta:
     *                           ftroLimit: valore entero como limite para reg a devolver
     *                           proyecto_id: ID de proyecto
     * @return array           [description]
     */
    public static function getTareasPendientes(SafeMySQL $db, $idEmp = 0, $aFiltro=array()){
        $ftroLimit = $proyecto_id = '';
        if(!empty($aFiltro) && is_array($aFiltro)){//condiciones esperadas
            if(isset($aFiltro['ftroLimit']) && $aFiltro['ftroLimit'] > 0){//se envia un valor entero como limite
                $ftroLimit = ' LIMIT '.$aFiltro['ftroLimit'];
            }
            if(isset($aFiltro['proyecto_id'])) $proyecto_id = $aFiltro['proyecto_id'];//se espera ID de proyecto
        }
        $sql = "SELECT t1.id, t1.solicitud, t2.responsable FROM Tareas t1
        INNER JOIN tareas_emp t2 ON t1.id = t2.tareas_id
        LEFT JOIN Proyectos t3 ON t1.proyecto_id = t3.id
        WHERE t1.estatus = 'Pendiente' ";
        if($idEmp > 0){
            $sql.= "AND t2.empleado_id = $idEmp ";
        }
        if($proyecto_id > 0){
            $sql.= "AND t3.id = $proyecto_id ";
        }
        $sql.= $ftroLimit;
        $data = $db->getAll($sql);
        return $data;
    }    

    public static function cancelTareasP(Usuario $_Usuario, $proyecto_id) {    

        $conex = $_Usuario->getConexBD();    

        if ($_Usuario instanceof Usuario) {
            $tipoUsuario = $_Usuario->getTipo();
            $nivelAcceso = $_Usuario->getPerfil()->get_nivelacc();
        }    

        $tareasPend = extract(Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex));
        $i = 0;    

        while ($i <= $tareasPend) {
            return $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id' AND id = '$tareasPend'");
            $i++;
        }    

        return regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $tareasPend, $proyecto_id);    

    }    

    ?>
```

Comment: Puesto que `getTareasPendientes` te devuelvo esto: `return $data;`, sería cuestión de leer esa variable y obtener de ella el dato que necesitas. No se ve exactamente lo que devuelve `getAll`. Si fuese un array, podrías obtener el id dentro de un bucle: `foreach ($data as $row){$id=$row["id"];}`

Comment: El `getAll` es una función auxiliar para obtener todas las filas del conjunto de resultados de la consulta y los argumentos opcionales.

Comment: Entiendo, lo que quiero decir es que, según la forma en que `getAll` devuelva los datos deberás leerlos para obtener el `id`. Sería útil para poder tener una respuesta que comentes la forma en que los datos son devueltos y si en la variable `$datos` se obtiene solamente una fila o si pueden obtenerse también varias filas.

Comment: Se obtienen varias filas, con un `print_r` esto es lo que arroja:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [solicitud] => Cancelar todas las tareas a la vez [responsable] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [solicitud] => Tesis [responsable] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [solicitud] => Tarea 3 [responsable] => 1 )... Y continúa hasta terminar de mostrar todas las tareas pendientes, al hacer el `foreach ($data as $row){$id=$row["id"];}` sólo toma el primer id, los demás no.

Answer (score 4):

### Problema

En tu comentario especificas que esto es lo que devuelve el método `getTareasPendientes`:

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [solicitud] => Cancelar todas las tareas a la vez
    [responsable] => 1
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [solicitud] => Tesis
    [responsable] => 1
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [solicitud] => Tarea 3
    )
```

Estás usando `extract()`, que, según la documentación de PHP:

> Devuelve el número de variables importadas con éxito a la tabla de
>   símbolos.

Además, `extract()` solo acepta un *array asociativo* como parámetro de entrada, en tu caso estas pasando un array indexado.

Para que esto te funcionase, tendrías que añadir un parámetro como `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` y añadir un prefijo como *myarray*. Siendo 0, 1 y 2 las claves del array indexado, estarías asignando sus valores a las variables $myarray_0, $myarray_1 y $myarray_2. Esto no nos sirve para lo que queremos hacer en este caso.

Es decir, en tu código estas asignando a `$tareasPend` el `count()` de ese array, o en este caso, 0 será el valor asignado, ya que la entrada del método `extract()` no es correcta, por lo que no está importando ninguna variable.

Por tanto, teniendo en cuenta tu `while` actual, estarías utilizando siempre la condición `id = 0` no el id real de cada una de las tareas. Por eso no es que te esté cogiendo solo el primer id como comentas, **esta asignado siempre el valor 0 que saca del** `extract()`

Además, estas haciendo un `return` dentro del bucle, lo que hace que tras la primera iteración se abandone la función. Por ello nunca podrás llegar a la `id` del segundo elemento del *array*, porque salimos en el primero.

---

### Solución

Un foreach te sirve perfectamente para solucionar el problema y no debes usar `extract()`.

Para ello, asigna el `Array` a `$tareasPend`:

`$tareasPend = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex);`

Y después itera sobre ellas en el foreach:

```
foreach ($tareasPend as $tarea) {
    $id_tarea = $tarea['id'];
    $conex->query("UPDATE Tareas SET estatus = 'Cancelada' WHERE proyecto_id = '$proyecto_id' AND id = '$id_tarea'");
}
```

---

#### Edito

Se me olvidaba comentarte que, ahora, en tu `return`:

`return regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $tareasPend, $proyecto_id);`

`$tareasPend` es un Array. Si necesitas pasar el número de tareas, tendrás que usar `count($tareasPend)`

---

#### Edición 2

Al hacer `return` dentro del `foreach`, estabas saliendo de la función y por eso no iterabas por todas las tareas. No uses `return` ahí. He editado la respuesta más arriba.

Comment: `$id_tarea = $tarea['id'];` sólo toma el primer `id` del array, los demás no, ya lo intenté de esta forma

Comment: Estás segura? Has probado mi código? Es imposible que solo coja el primer id del array, ya que $tarea es una entrada de $tareasPend. Has eliminado el extract del código y probado el funcionamiento?

Comment: También he intentado con un `print_r($id_tarea)` y sólo arroja el primer `id`, al momento de querer cancelar las tareas no hace ningún cambio en el `estatus` de la tarea y en el registro histórico sólo coloca el primer `id`, lo he intentado con tu código.

Comment: Si quitas el `extract()` al asignar `$tareasPend`, y haces un `print_r` de ella, que te devuelve? El array que he puesto en la respuesta? Es decir, prueba `$tareasPend = Tarea::getTareasPendientes($conex); print_r($tareasPend);`

Comment: `print_r(tareasPend)` me devuelve lo que puse en los comentarios, `Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [solicitud] => Cancelar todas las tareas a la vez [responsable] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [solicitud] => Tesis [responsable] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [solicitud] => Tarea 3 [responsable] => 1 )`, sin usar el extract().

Comment: Vale, revisa mi respuesta. Creo que he encontrado el error. No utilices `return` dentro del `foreach`, ya que a la primera pasada del `foreach` estas haciendo `return` y **sales de la función**, por eso no te saca nada más que la primera id.

Comment: Ya cencela las tareas, pero en registro histórico me arroja 21, que es el número total de tareas registradas, ya sea que su `estatus` sea `Cancelada` o `Pendiente` o cualquier otro, esa línea de código está así: `return regHistorico($conex, 4, 'Tareas', $id_tarea, $proyecto_id);`.

Comment: `$id_tarea` no tiene sentido que se la pases a `regHistorico`. Necesitaría ver que hace ese método, pero estoy seguro de que tienes que pasarle el array entero de `$tareasPend`, porque ahí le estas pasando la `id` de la última tarea que hemos cancelado en el `foreach`.

Comment: Me sale este error: Warning: html_entity_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in...

Comment: Para solucionarte esto necesito ver el otro código, en el que tengas ese método `html_entity_decode()`. Amplia tu pregunta bajo una etiqueta de Edito y editaré yo mi respuesta acorde a ello :) En ese *Edito* añade los cambios que has hecho hasta ahora para que todo vaya funcionando.